# Best way to show a loading screen in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm building what is essentially a web app. Every piece of data has to be fetched from a web API. So, every UITableView that I show takes some amount of time to fill with data and I'm struggling to find a good way to show the user a loading screen.

Right now I'm popping up an action sheet, but that just seems a bit wrong. Ideally, I'd popup up a blank view over the tableview with "Loading..." on it, then fade it away when the data comes in, but I can't think of a way to do that in 8 places in my app without massive code duplication.

Comment: This kind of thing is /completely/ context dependent, which makes SO a sort of bad place for quality answers (although you will get some). Basically you have to look into the design of your application. A very simple solution is to throw up this loading screen as a UI view and use notifications and delegates to minimize duplicated code (e.g., you could have a class that throws up a shielding screen and waits for a notification/delegate call--when your view controller finishes loading all its stuff, it can notify that class, which then removes itself).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

there are two options for you according to me.

1. Use an alertview
2. Use MBProgressHUD.

---

- For alertView You have to place a UIAlertView variable in .h file.
  Then place following code - when you are requesting/loading data.

  `av=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading Data" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];`
  `ActInd=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];`
  `[ActInd startAnimating];`
  `[ActInd setFrame:CGRectMake(125, 60, 37, 37)];`
  `[av addSubview:ActInd];`
  `[av show];`

Now, place following statement when you have finished your processing.

`[av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];`
`[av release]; av=nil;`

- Another way is using [MBProgressHUD](http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD)
- It's very useful & ready made for you - you just have to follow these steps.

---

1. Download it from given link
2. Import Both file to your project ( copy not link )
3. `#import "MBProgressHUD.h"` - import this where you want to use progress view.
4. `MBProgressHUD *mbProcess;` - declare a variable in *.h file.
5. Place following code when you are processing ( in *.m file )

`mbProcess=[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];`
`mbProcess.labelText=@"Loading Data";`
`[self.view addSubview:mbProcess];`
`[mbProcess setDelegate:self];`
`[mbProcess show:YES];`

7. When your processing is done place this line. `[mbProcess hide:YES];`
8. Don't forget to add delegate method of MBProgressHUD in you *.m file. like this

`#pragma mark -`
`#pragma mark MBProgressHUDDelegate methods`

```
- (void)hudWasHidden {
    // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
    [mbProcess removeFromSuperview];
    [mbProcess release];
}
```

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but I just found it and it's very helpful, but I'm just wondering if it would be possible to allow the user to still access a navigation bar behind this alert so that they could leave the page if loading takes too long. Or does an alert view not allow it? Thanks!

Comment: Your usage of MBProgressHUD was incorrect. See the github repo for a better usage.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a nice looking spinner, look at http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD